# How to treat a duration of chronic disease

Tags: regression, control-group

I have a data set that contains information about

1. healthy dogs;
2. dogs that have chronic heart disease; and
3. dogs that have the same disease, but are considered as a
   long-livers.

**(All dogs in this data were alive at the moment of all measurement)**. 
I would like to check if some biological parameter **$X$** has effect on how long dogs can live with this chronic disease. **Again, all dogs are alive.**

I wanted to account for the baseline level of $X$, so I separated healthy dogs to groups by sex, age and etc.; then I calculated averaged **$\bar{X}$**'s for each group and subtracted them from the X's of all sick dogs while controlling for group assignment. The new variable (say, $Diff$) presents the deflection of $X$ in sick dogs with respect to the averaged $X$ of the healthy groups. Since only sick dogs have duration of the chronic disease, now I can apply simple regression on the duration with $Diff$ as an explanatory variable.

Is there any better way to do such analysis? What kind of biases this analysis involves and can they be controlled in different way?

Comment: Seems like a problem in survival analysis. I suppose that the dogs die from the disease (otherwise it wouldn't be called chronic), whereas the long-livers correspond to censored observations.

Comment: (Un)fortunately, I have double-checked, and all dogs are alive. I 100% agree with you, because it does look like a survival analysis, but I would not be asking questions here in this case. :) The data contains also blood pressure and different measurements that were taken during the last vet visit. The duration of the disease is the duration at the time that the $X$ was measured. The disease is chronic, but it does not mean that dog cannot live with it long enough. If dog lives 8-9 years with this disease it can be considered as long-liver. This group is also older, but still alive.

Comment: The duration of disease is usually defined as the time from acquiring the disease to recovery or lethal outcome. In your case it is defined from acquiring the disease to the arbitrary moment of observation. That is you are asking "for how long the dogs have been living with disease". You could adapt the survival analysis to do it backward in time... but it remains a poorly formulated question. It is more meaningful to ask at what age the dogs acquire the disease (survival analysis from birth to acquiring the disease) or studying how various parameters evolve with progression if the disease.

Comment: I understand everything, and this is why I am here. I have a data (not mine), a hypothesis (not mine) and understanding that I probably cannot test the hypothesis with this data. The analysis I have explained is the only thing I came up with and I think that it is very problematic and biased. Is that right?

Comment: We've been discussing it as if it were a longitudinal or even cohort study. But, if this is a cross-sectional study, then, of course the dead dogs do not appear in it! You need to look at the distribution of sick dogs by the time since acquiring the disease: there will be lots with 1 and 2 years and very few with 6-8.

Comment: It is a cross-sectional study. The problem is that because all dogs are alive, the dogs with 1-2 years can potentially be a long-livers, so the duration of disease is a source of biases. I already took a look at the distribution of disease duration, and the $X$ (parameter that mostly affected by age and sex) has no effect on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101095/discussion-between-art-and-vadim).